# kivy:apk from buildozer didn't work in android

Tags: android, kivy, apk, buildozer

I made some transit information App through buildozer and I am testing the app.

apk build from buildozer was successful.

Phone : **Samsung S7 Edge (Android 7.0)**

OS : **Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS**

I acquired the apk file from buildozer; installed and launched it in my S7 edge.
There is no problem in my desktop, but the application is crashing. 
When I open the app, it goes out immediately.
I spent almost three days on this, but I could not find a solution.
Is there a solution here? Thank you for reading.

main.py

```
__version__ = "1.0"
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import kivy
import os
kivy.require('1.10.0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.clock import Clock

class Loading_Screen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Loading_Screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.callNext, 2) 

    def callNext(self,dt): 
        self.manager.current = 'Before_First_Screen'

class Load_BusInfo():
    pass

class Before_First_Screen(Screen):
    pass

class First_Screen(Screen):
    pass

class Test_Screen(Screen):
    pass

###################목적지_역명#####################

class DTN_TECHNOPARK(Screen): 
    pass

class DTN_BITZONE(Screen): 
    pass

class DTN_INUSTATION(Screen): 
    pass

class Bus_Information(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Bus_Information, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        with open(u'C:/Users/mg/Desktop/TubucTest/station/동막역(1번출구)ICB164000039.txt') as businfo:
            Businfo= [] 
            nolinenum=businfo.readline()
            while nolinenum!='': 
                Businfo.append(nolinenum)
                leftstations = (businfo.readline().rstrip('\n') + ' 정거장'.rstrip('\n'))
                lefttime = (businfo.readline().rstrip('\n') + ' 초'.rstrip('\n'))
                nolinenum = businfo.readline().rstrip('\n')
                Businfo.append(leftstations)
                Businfo.append(lefttime)
            self.businfolist = Businfo
            self.lenbil = int(len(Businfo))
            self.numberoflist = int(len(Businfo)/3)

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file("testmain.kv")

class TubucApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return presentation

TubucApp().run()
```

buildozer.spec

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = TUBUC

# (str) Package name
package.name = tubuc

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,txt,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 1.0

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python2,kivy

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 2.7

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.10.0

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET

# (int) Android API to use
android.api = 24

# (int) Minimum API required
#android.minapi = 9

# (int) Android SDK version to use
android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
android.ndk = 16b

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to stable
#p4a.branch = stable

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (list) Android additionnal libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

testmain.kv

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#:import NoTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.NoTransition
#:import Label kivy.uix.button.Label

ScreenManagement:
    transition: NoTransition()
    Loading_Screen:
    Before_First_Screen:
    First_Screen:
    Test_Screen:
    DTN_TECHNOPARK:
    DTN_BITZONE:
    DTN_INUSTATION:
    Bus_Information:

<Loading_Screen>:
    name: 'Loading_Screen'
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'image/Loading_Screen.png'

<Before_First_Screen>:
    name: 'Before_First_Screen'
    Button:
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
                source: 'image/BBG2.png'
        on_release:
            app.root.current = 'First_Screen'

<First_Screen>:
    name: 'First_Screen'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        spacing: 50 # spacing between button
        padding: [50, 50, 50, 50]
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size 
                source: 'image/background.png' #backgroundimage
        Button:
            id: dongmak
            width: 40
            pos_hint: {'x' : 0, 'y':.45}
            size_hint: [.6,.1]
            background_normal:'image/2.png'
            background_down:'image/after.png'
            border: (0,0,0,0)
            on_release: app.root.current = 'Bus_Information'
        Button:
            id: campustown
            color: 100,100,100,100 #text_color
            width: 40
            pos_hint: {'x' : 0, 'y':.45}
            size_hint: [.6,.1]
            background_normal:'image/3.png'
            background_down:'image/after.png'
            border: (0,0,0,0)
            on_release: app.root.current = 'DTN_BITZONE'
        Button:
            id: technopark
            color: 100,100,100,100 #text_color
            pos_hint: {'x' : 0, 'y':.45}
            size_hint: [.6,.1]
            background_normal:'image/4.png'
            background_down:'image/after.png'
            border: (0,0,0,0)
            on_release: app.root.current = 'DTN_INUSTATION'
        Button:
            id: bitzone
            width: 40
            pos_hint: {'x' : 0, 'y':.45}
            size_hint: [.6,.1]
            background_normal:'image/5.png'
            background_down:'image/after.png'
            border: (0,0,0,0)   
        Button:
            id: inustation
            width: 40
            pos_hint: {'x' : 0, 'y':.45}
            size_hint: [.6,.1]
            background_normal:'image/1.png'
            background_down:'image/after.png'
            border: (0,0,0,0)
            #font_size: 15
            #text: 'inustation'
<Test_Screen>:
    name: 'Test_Screen'

    Button:
        on_release: app.root.current = 'First_Screen'
        text: 'back to the home screen'
        font_size: 50

############destionation_station_name################
<DTN_TECHNOPARK>:
    name: 'DTN_TECHNOPARK'

    Button:
        on_release: app.root.current = 'First_Screen'
        text: 'destionation >> technopark'
        font_size: 50

<DTN_BITZONE>:
    name: 'DTN_BITZONE'

    Button:
        on_release: app.root.current = 'First_Screen'
        text: 'destionation >> bitzone'
        font_size: 50

<DTN_INUSTATION>:
    name: 'DTN_INUSTATION'

    Button:
        on_release: app.root.current = 'First_Screen'
        text: 'destionation >> inustation'
        font_size: 50
######################################################
<Bus_Information>:
    name: 'Bus_Information'
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size 
            source: 'image/destination/a.png' #backgroundimage

    #for sero in range(root.numberoflist):
    #   for garo in range(3):


    GridLayout:
        cols: 3
        rows: root.numberoflist
        spacing: 0
        padding: [0,100]
        on_parent:
            for i in range(root.lenbil): txt = root.businfolist[i]; self.add_widget(Label(text =txt, text_size=(cm(2), cm(2)), font_name='C:/Windows/Fonts/HYWULM', 
            pos=self.pos, id=txt, color=(255,255,255,1)))
```

Comment: i think ## class Bus_Information(Screen): ## this part is wrong. i just ran this app without this class. and the application is worked fine. but i don't know where is wrong with this part.

Comment: One possibility is that the app can't find the image referenced for your `Bus_Information` class. Try adding `source.include_patterns = destination/*.png` to your `buildozer.spec`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson nah it does not work :(

Comment: Another thing: in your `GridLayout` under `Bus_Information`, your reference `font_name='C:/Windows/Fonts/HYWULM'`. Not gonna work on Android.

Answer (score 0):

1. python file must be named main.py
2. kivy file name must be without capital letters
3. kivy file must be imported with Builder.load_file or Builder.load_string("""
   kivy code
   """)
   Dont forget add it in the begginng "from Builder.lang import Builder" or something like that
4. add pillow at "Application requirements" (about line 39) in .spec file (you need it because of your image)
5. also add the version of kivy at the requirements like kivy==2.1.0 for example
6. I dont know the font you used but if you downloaded it from somewhere. First add these font type to the other python and kivy file before compiling
   Then at the spec file "Source files to include" (at the very beginning) add the data type ttf so; ...atlas,ttf
   If you dont downloaded it please ask someone else
   Also add the image file to the other python and kivy files before compiling

I think it was everything. Hope it helped